# Trying to create a simple javascript gallery with a next and previous buttons to loop back to the beginning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kind of new Javascript. I'm trying to create a a simple gallery with a next and previous button that will loop these images to the front when clicked. I'm managed to find a few tutorials and bits to get images to click through, but however I'm stuck on what I'm doing wrong. The next/previous button is at the top left and would like to be centred around the thumbnails pictures like previous on the top left, next on the top right of the thumbnail pictures. I've been to the local library and still cannot figure this out.

What am I doing wrong and how to correct it? Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test2.css">
<title>Simple Playing Around</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var photos=new Array()
 var which=0
 photos[0]='http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png'
 photos[1]='http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png'
 photos[2]='http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png'
 photos[3]='http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png'

 function backward(){
    if (which > 0){
        which=which-1
        document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which]
    }
 }   
      function backward(){
    if (which>0){
     which=which-1;
    } else {
     which=photos.length-1;
    }
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
 }

 function forward(){
    if (which<photos.length-1){
     which=which+1;
    } else {
     which=0;
    }
   document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
 }
 }

 </script>

 <form>
     <input type="button" value="&lt;&lt;Back" onClick="backward()"> 
     <input type="button" value="Next&gt;&gt;" onClick="forward()">
 </form>

<body>

<div class="gallery" align="center">
<h3>Thumbnails</h3>

<div class="thumbnails">
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" name="img2" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" name="img3" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" name="img4" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" name="img5" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" name="img6" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img7.src" name="img7" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt="cat" />
</div>

<div class="preview" align="center">
<img name="preview" src="http://i67.tinypic.com/20uv0vp.png" alt=""/>
</div>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    function forward()
    {
        which++;
        if(which>photos.length-1)
        {
            which=0;
        }
        document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
    }

function backward()
{
    --which;
    if(which<1)
    {
        which=photos.length-1;
    }
    document.images.photoslider.src=photos[which];
}
```